# I've tried converting a HTML site to WordPress but only the content is displayed and the CSS is not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want a HTML site to be converted to a WordPress site with the same theme.

I've added the 'wp_enqueue_style' to the `functions.php` file for WordPress to find the CSS file but still it's not working.

1. **functions.php**

```
<?php

function our_theme_dependencies(){ ?>

    <script>alert("its working"); </script>

    <?php

    //css libraries
    wp_enqueue_style('main-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/css/jquery.bxslider.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('plugin-set', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/css/plugin.css');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'our_theme_dependencies');

?>
```

2. **front-page.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <div class="notice-board-row">
            <div class="container notice-board-container">
                <div class="notice-board-wraper">
                    <h3>Notice Board</h3>
                    <div class="notice-board-slider">
                        <div class="notice-item">
                            <div class="date">
                                <span class="month">Jan</span>
                                <span class="no">22</span>
                                <span class="year">2020</span>
                            </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I am expecting the same theme as in the HTML version of the site to be converted to WordPress site.

Comment: Delete the `<script>` tag you have inside your `our_theme_dependencies()` function, that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Also, please share the contents of your `header.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

[converted html page to wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do9PK.png)

css is not working